# Gecode constraint "each value in array appears at least k times"

Tags: c++, constraint-programming, gecode

it's Gecode c++

I have an IntVarArgs value of length n and I want to push a constraint that each value in array appears at least k times (or 0)
f.e array [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4] satisfies this constraint with k = 2

what I do now is

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    count(*this, a, a[i], IRT_GQ, k);
}
```

However, as n grows, the number of constraints grows, but I feel like it could be expressed by a single constraint. I also think that closure of array to itself is not optimal for the solver.

Comment: This sounds like you need a global cardinality constraint. In MiniZinc, which compiles down to gecode, you would use [`global_cardinality_low_up`](http://www.minizinc.org/doc-lib/doc-globals-counting.html) and set the up-bounds to the array length. I'm pretty sure gecode includes a propogator for this contraint, maybe it was called `GCC`. When you know the array length, it might also suffice to constrain the `nvalues` of the array.

Comment: global_cardinality_low_up doesn't allow me to say each value occurs from a to b times or doesn't occur at all, does it? it looks like I can only make some specific values {i} occurs from a_i to b_i times

Comment: No, I'm sorry if I misread that. In the case that is every value `i` is counted between `a_i` and `b_i`, or zero times you would use the `global_cardinality` predicate with the a variables `v_i` with the domain `{0,a_i,..,b_i}`.